# How do you call a Word method and pass parameters?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I want to get a word document and also use some of the parameters as documented in the MS docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220317%28v=office.11%29.aspx

I have no problem passing in the first argument, the file name but trying to add any of the other arguments seems to do nothing. What is the correct LotusScript syntax to pass in these arguments?

I tried the following with no result (it did open the document object however).

```
Set worddoc = word.Documents.Open( Dirname + "basedoc.doc", False, False, False, ,,, ,,, , True,, , , )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED REPLACED CODE SAMPLE WITH ENTIRE WORKING AGENT:

Option Public

Option Declare

Sub Initialize

```
Dim filepath As String
Dim wordDoc As Variant
Dim word As Variant

Set word = CreateObject("Word.Application")

filepath="C:\test"
Set wordDoc = word.Documents.Open(filePath &".doc", False, True, False)
word.visible=True
```

End Sub

This is working code, you will need a file named test.doc in the root of the c: drive for this to work, but this does work, I just ran it successfully, test with this and modify from there.

Comment: Erik, what do you pass in for the parameters that need either a string (for passwords) or for the format parameter? I don't want a password or format, but, ran into issues either passing an empty paramater (just commas) or a empty string (""). Do you have an example of using all the parameters?  thanks!  Howard

Comment: I think I got it now, the following works:Set worddoc = word.Documents.Open( Dirname + "basedoc.doc", False, false, False,,,True,,,0,37, true, False, True,0)  I had to find the constant values for some of the settings.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it in LotusScript but there are examples of using Apache POI for this.  As long as it can be a back end process. need to use the "X" api.

Comment: Paul, it has to be LotusScript, maintaining an OLD Domino app with about a 2000 line webquerysave agent that opens Word docs, modifies them and reattaches. Having issues with some docs opening and I think some of the parameters on the open would help out.